# Why is useState calling my function early

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that is equivalent to this:

```
const PickAShell = () => {
    const [functionToRun, setFunctionToRun] = useState(() => {});
    const [shellPicked, setShellPicked] = useState(0);
    const shells = [1,2,3,4,5];

    const pickShellFn = (shellNumber, onConfirm) => {
        setFunctionToRun(onConfirm);
        setShellPicked(shellNumber);
    }
    const win = () => setShellPicked(0)
      && alert('You Win');
    const lose = (shellNumber) => setShellPicked(0)
      && alert('nothing under shell '+shellNumber)
    return (
    <div>
        {shells.map(shellNumber => {
            const clickHandler = shellNumber%2?
                () => pickShellFn(shellNumber, () => win())
              : () => pickShellFn(shellNumber, () => lose(shellNumber));
            return <Button onClick={clickHandler}>{`pick shell number ${shellNumber}`}</Button> 
     }) }
    {shellPicked? (<Button onClick={functionToRun}>Reveal Shell</Button>): null}
    </div>
    )
}
```

What I'm seeing is that when I run it, and I click the equivalent of the 'pick shell number X' button and it runs the function (win/lose) early.

In the chrome dev tools, it's calling 'setFunctionToRun' and immediately calling the function (lose).

What I'm expecting is, that after clicking say 'pick shell number 2' button, it should set the `functionToRun` to the `() => win()` fat arrow function. And then only when clicking 'Reveal Shell' button should it call anything.

Comment: Have you tried `setFunctionToRun(() => onConfirm)`

Comment: @JakeLuby that would look nicer but I think is functional the same as my answer?

Comment: No, it's not functionally the same.  Actually it was a typo it should be `setFunctionToRun(() => onConfirm())`.  You could also do `<Button onClick={() => functionToRun}>`.  The reason you're seeing it popup is that react thinks it needs to run that function as part of the render process, instead of during onClick().  One way around this is to forward the function call.

Comment: The better way would be to find in your code why the function is being run instead of passed through, but I'm having issues w/ codesandbox right now and couldn't get anything running

Comment: @JakeLuby some how I read your first message as the same code as in your second. I thought I was called as `setFunctionToRun` is treating the passed call back as a function that returns the new state, as opposed to being the new state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to make clickHandler like so:

```
const clickHandler = shellNumber%2?
            () => pickShellFn(shellNumber, () => () => win())
          : () => pickShellFn(shellNumber, () => () => lose(shellNumber));
```

Now when the function is called it returns the inner function, ready to be called by the reveal button.

This is because `useState` can be called [with a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setPartOfState(prevState => doSomethingWith(previousState))
```

This means that the alternative would be to, instead of the above, call:

```
setFunctionToRun(() => onConfirm);
```

Which uses the same signature, but does not use the previous state or call `onConfirm`. If this anonymous function wasn't there it would call `onConfirm` at this point instead of just passing it in.